# See if there is a leasing in a selected period of time

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I need help again. I am vurrently working on a sample project. And there I have a listBox with cars that are available for the selected period of time. This period of time is selected through DateTime-Control in Windows Forms.

So I've got a loop (foreach) where I delete all of the list entries which are not available for the selected time period.

it looks like this

```
int recordsRemoved = availableCars.RemoveAll(f =>f.ObjectID == v.Car &&  dtStartDate.Value >= v.StartDate | dtEndDate.Value <= v.EndDate);
```

dtStartDate is the Windows Forms Control and v.StartDate is the StartDate from the rent in my DataBase.

I hope it is understandable so far...

As you can probably tell, my "if" doesn't work the way I want to. What I need is an option where it deletes every car which is already rent from (for example) 10.05.2016 to 17.05.2016.

When I select 10.05.2016 to 17.05.2016 I don't want any car to be in the list which would be (for example) rent from 12.05.2016 to 23.05.2016.

Well, once again, I hope I could explain it so that you can understand it.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You probably also need to make sure `dtStartDate.Value <= v.EndDate` and `dtEndDate.Value >= v.StartDate`. After that, some carefully placed parentheses would help make it more readable.

Comment: `|` is not the same as `||`. First is a bit operator, second is a boolean operator. And I'm sure you need the second version. And as @p.s.w.g said, you need parenthesis when using an `or` operator combined with an `and` operator.

Comment: Try refining your condition like `f.ObjectID == v.Car &&  dtStartDate.Value >= v.StartDate && dtEndDate.Value <= v.EndDate);`

Comment: @MasterDJon FYI, `|` is also operates on bools; it's just the non-short-circuiting version of `||` (i.e. it always evaluates both sides even if it's not necessary for determining the result of the operation). See [|| Operator (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)

Comment: @p.s.w.g I tried your option and added these code samples to my code. But now it won't show me the car which is on rent even if I select a time period where it should be free

Comment: @HariPrasad i already tried it how you said. the problem there is like that. I have a rent of an Ford Focus from 25.04.2016 to 29.04.2016. now the users wants to see available cars from 25.04.2016 to 30.04.2016. If I do it like you said, the Ford Focus will show up, because the end date is bigger than the end date in the rent. But actually, you can't rent the ford focus for this time period due to its inavailability from 25.04 to 29.04. I know I am most likely explaining it way more complicated than it is

Answer (score 0):

Try `Where` like below:

```
int recordsRemoved = availableCars.RemoveAll(availableCars.Where(f =>f.ObjectID == v.Car &&  dtStartDate.Value >= v.StartDate && dtEndDate.Value <= v.EndDate));
```